# Sound & Broadcast Icons Missing?

Tags: panel, indicator, menu, ayatana

I had the sound icon in the main menu bar up top, along with the default Broadcast icon up there. All of a sudden they are missing and I can't find them. I can't find them in the Add to Panel menu either. How do I get them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the "Indicator Applet". It should be available from the Add to Panel menu.

Comment: What if you do that, and nothing happens when you click add? When I did this I had to first remove the indicator applet session panel (with the shutdown button on it) it then re-spawned the bar with the indicator applet showing correctly (and the session panel remaining too). I have the weather report, clock, lock screen, and system monitor panels working fine otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that you've removed the indicator applet from your panel. Right click on the panel, and select `Add to Panel`, then search for the indicator applet.

[image]

Note: I've blurred out the non-default entries I have in my menu so not to confuse.

Answer (score 1):

Sound should be under Indicator Applet.

Comment: Indicator Applet Session is what displays the "Shut Down, etc." menu.

Comment: My bad ignore session applet ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to right click on the panel and choose `Add to panel...` Then scroll down until you find the applet called `Indicator Applet`. Just add it and the controls/menus should be back.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 14.04 launch dconf editor **com**>**canonical**>**indicator**>**sound** and check the **visible** option