# Sound not working after 12.04 install

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have recently installed 12.04, but the sound is not working from both internal speakers, and from headphones when I connect them.

I have followed the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems to no avail and submitted a bug report. I've also tried running alsamixer and unmuting a few more things, but that didn't work.

I've tried to upgrade alsa sound drivers by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)
```

however on the last command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-alsa-driver-modules-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-alsa-driver-modules-3.2.0-24-generic-pae'
```

What should I do to try get sound functioning?

It might be worth noting that 10.04 previously ran on this machine with no sound problems.

Comment: tried changing the devices to correct option?

Comment: @VineetMenon yeah, I have.

Comment: If you type pulseaudio into your terminal do you get this message ? E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running. E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

Comment: Install Gnome alsa Mixer. Set the master control to its Maximum. Check your hardware too. Look at this also - http://askubuntu.com/questions/24722/no-sound-after-boot

Comment: yes, I do get that message.

Comment: Then that means I'm having the same problem you are :( I'm not sure where to find the main.c code, but I think it might be interesting to look at and see why it's breaking. Maybe file permissions?

Comment: provide the output to this command --> strace aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav If there are any files not not found or errors than this will lead you to the
problem.

Comment: Silly question : What is your sound card ? the sound stack under Linux is quite complex and solutions differs from one soundcard to another. you'll find it by typing on a terminal lspci or lsusb if it doesn't appear with lspci. Also is this the first time that this computer has linux ? did you had sound before and with what linux ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What solved this problem in my case was [posted over at the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1974241&page=2).

Append `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` with the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Then restart your Ubuntu system.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I tried changing the `alsa-base.conf` file, but with no luck. What did work for me was adding `snd-hda-intel` to the end of the `etc/modules` file, as recommended here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1961136

Answer (score 3):

Just delete / rename the hidden file and folder **.pulse** and **.pulse-cookie** and then reboot.

If that doesn't work, try to install the package **pavucontrol**

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. pavucontrol is also already installed and running that and changing settings didn't work :(

Comment: This one worked for me, but my sound stopped working after some sectors of my hard disk (/home partition) were recovered.