# Sound is not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I am Using ubuntu 16.04 on ASUS X555L. sound was working correctly but instantly it just not working.

I have try every possible solution given on internet but still blank .

My sound setting does not have any output device even my headphone is attached.

I have try speaker also but does not work.

here is some link that i already try:

[Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04LTS after upgrading from 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544618/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-after-upgrading-from-13-10)

[Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631763/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04lts)

[Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457619/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)
[Sound not working after 12.04 install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130809/sound-not-working-after-12-04-install)

[Tried to install audio driver for ASUS P5K, now sound is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501248/tried-to-install-audio-driver-for-asus-p5k-now-sound-is-not-working)
[Ubuntu Sound Problems Asus K52F](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536210/ubuntu-sound-problems-asus-k52f)

[image]

If any other option other than installing ubuntu again ?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? What is 16.x, 16.0, etc? Is it 16.04, or 16.10?

Comment: 16.04 LTS version

Comment: Have you resolved thus @ShubhamBatra. I face similar issues on my Asus lappie as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try  this [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/asus-x555ub-realtek-alc256-no-sound).  Run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
echo options snd-hda-intel model=auto | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Check all mutes and unmute them through:

```
sudo alsamixer
```

Then run:

```
shutdown -h now
```

Comment: worked like a charm on my HP 840 G1

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm on my inspiron 15 5000 series.

Comment: "cannot open mixer: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot. Open a terminal again and type (ignore any errors with the rm command):

```
rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

reboot as:

```
sudo init 6
```

The open your terminal and:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
sudo init 6
```

Plug your earphone and start some .mp3's

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem and i had tried everything but couldn't able to resolved the problem then i figured out that it wasn't the driver causing the problem it was keyring password that i had provided so if you tried everything ,try to reset your keyring password to blank

Go to System/Preferences/Password and Encryption keys, right click the appropriate folder and click Change Password. Put in your old password and leave the new one blank.
its worked for me , try it may works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, worked for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Now add the following line at the end of the file, or if `model=generic` change it to `model=auto`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the answer of Silas Miranda.  Could you develop why you think your approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. And the reason behind it was that I was logged in to gdm using root. And pulseaudio doesn't have that access. Luckily I found out this problem and the solution is following.

> pulseaudio -D

Comment: You'd start the pulseaudio daemon with this command. As you can see in the picture the sound dialog opens - so pulseaudio runs already

Answer (score 0):

**100% works**
Paste and run the below command in the terminal.

```
pactl list | grep -oP 'Sink #\K([0-9]+)' | while read -r i ; do pactl -- set-sink-volume $i +100% ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If it stops suddenly, just do a force reload of pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```