# No Sound in Ubuntu 18.04 on ASUSFX503VD

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, asus, soundcard

I've tried every solutions on the web, changed alsamixer, pavucontrol...
everything. But nothing seem to work. Please help. In the beginning, Ubuntu didn't boot, tried some solutions and now everything is fine except Sound(most important), <kbd>fn</kbd> key not working, brightness control keys not working.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? What was the system like the last time you had sound on this computer, can you get sound by plugging in speakers/headphones? also it may be helpful to provide links to some of the solutions you tried.

Comment: This is my new laptop pre-installed with windows 10, (I am using ubuntu since 2 years on Dell laptop and everything was fine there). Neither earphone is working nor inbuilt speakers are working.I tried `https://askubuntu.com/questions/802016/sound-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04` , `https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1406868` @Jeff

Comment: did you test to see if the sound was working in windows 10?

Comment: Yeah everything is perfect on windows 10 @Jeff

Comment: Upgrading to kernel 5 solved the issue